# Data in RecyclerView not being passed from Fragment to Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

After creating a `RecyclerView`, I noticed that the strings I have declared within a `Bundle` are not getting passed from the `Fragment` to the `AlertDialog`, and the connected text views appear blank. Does anyone know what has gone wrong? Do I need to use an intent for this scenario or something else?

**Used in fragment:**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("goalreached",  getResources().getString(R.string.goal_reached));
bundle.putString("day",  getResources().getString(R.string.today));
bundle.putString("distance",  getResources().getString(R.string._3_2_km));
bundle.putString("calories",  getResources().getString(R.string._213_kcal));
```

**Used in adapter:**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String goalreached = bundle.getString("goalreached");   
String day = bundle.getString("day");
String distance = bundle.getString("distance");                        
String calories = bundle.getString("calories");
```

[image]

**expected result**

[image]

**current result**

[image]

**fragment class**

```
public class TabFragmentRV extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public TabFragmentRV() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();
        assert v != null;

        mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("goalreached",  getResources().getString(R.string.goal_reached));
        bundle.putString("day",  getResources().getString(R.string.today));
        bundle.putString("distance",  getResources().getString(R.string._3_2_km));
        bundle.putString("calories",  getResources().getString(R.string._213_kcal));

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        initRVAdapter();
    }

    private void initRVAdapter(){
        List<Object> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();

        itemsList.add(new RVLineSeparator());
        itemsList.add(new RVTable("Stats", "Today", "Yesterday", "This week", "This month"));

        RVItemsAapter itemsListAdapter = new RVItemsAapter(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemsListAdapter);

        itemsListAdapter.setCallSMSFeed(itemsList);
        itemsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**adapter class**

```
public class RVItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final static int TYPE_TABLE = 1, TYPE_SEPARATOR = 2;
    private ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
    private Context context;

    public RVItemsAdapter(Context context){
        this. context=context;
    }

    public void setCallSMSFeed(List<Object> myArrayList){
        this.myArrayList = (ArrayList) myArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (myArrayList.get(position) instanceof TableRV) {
            return TYPE_TABLE;
        } else if (myArrayList.get(position) instanceof RVLineSeparator) {
            return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Item at position " + position + " is not an instance of either Phonecall or SMSmessage");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType=holder.getItemViewType();
        switch (viewType){
            case TYPE_TABLE:
                TableRV tblRV = (TableRV) myArrayList.get(position);
                ((TblViewHolder)holder).bind(tblRV);
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                ((SeparatorViewHolder)holder).showSeparatorDetails();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected viewType: " + viewType);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){return myArrayList.size();}

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        int layout;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        switch (viewType){
            case TYPE_TABLE:
                layout = R.layout.cardview_tableview_withexpandability;
                View tblView = LayoutInflater
                        .from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new TblViewHolder(tblView);
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                layout = R.layout.lineseparatorforrecyclerview;
                View separatorView = LayoutInflater
                        .from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new SeparatorViewHolder(separatorView);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected viewType: " + viewType);
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    public class TblViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final Typeface iconFont = FontManager.getTypeface(context, FontManager.FONTAWESOME);

        private Button btnToday, btnYesterday, btnThisWeek, btnThisMonth;
        private TextView arrowexpandcollapseTextView, sectionNameTextView;

        TblViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            btnMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).create();

                    alertDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL,"OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });


                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_stats, null);
                    alertDialog.setView(content);

                    Bundle bundle = getBundle();
                    String goalreached = bundle.getString("goalreached");   
                    String day = bundle.getString("day");
                    String distance = bundle.getString("distance");                        
                    String calories = bundle.getString("calories");


                    ImageView imgdialogMain = content.findViewById(R.id.imgView_genderA);
                    ivGenderA.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_male);

                    TextView tvGoalReached = content.findViewById(R.id.txtView_dialog_goalreached);
                    tvGoalReached.setText(goalreached);


                    TextView tvDay = content.findViewById(R.id.txtView_day);
                    tvDay.setText(day);

                    TextView tvImgviewWalking = content.findViewById(R.id.imgView_walking);


                    TextView tvDistance = content.findViewById(R.id.txtView_distance);
                    tvDistance.setText(distance);

                    TextView tvImgviewFire = content.findViewById(R.id.imgView_fire);

                    TextView tvCaloriesBurned = content.findViewById(R.id.txtView_location);
                    tvCaloriesBurned.setText(calories);

                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the first created bundle into your adapter (probably when you create it)

Here is the class with the necessary changes

```
public class RVItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final static int TYPE_TABLE = 1, TYPE_SEPARATOR = 2;
    private ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
    private Context context;
    //Added Global bundle
    Private Bundle mBundle;

    public RVItemsAdapter(Context context){
        this. context=context;
    }

    //Added Constructor
    public RVItemsAdapter(Context context, Bundle bundle){
        this.context=context;
        this.mBundle = bundle;
    } 

    public void setCallSMSFeed(List<Object> myArrayList){
        this.myArrayList = (ArrayList) myArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (myArrayList.get(position) instanceof TableRV) {
            return TYPE_TABLE;
        } else if (myArrayList.get(position) instanceof RVLineSeparator) {
            return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Item at position " + position + " is not an instance of either Phonecall or SMSmessage");
    }

    //Update Bundle
    public void updateView(Bundle bundle){
        mBundle = bundle;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType=holder.getItemViewType();
        switch (viewType){
            case TYPE_TABLE:
                TableRV tblRV = (TableRV) myArrayList.get(position);
                ((TblViewHolder)holder).bind(tblRV);
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                ((SeparatorViewHolder)holder).showSeparatorDetails();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected viewType: " + viewType);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){return myArrayList.size();}

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        int layout;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        switch (viewType){
            case TYPE_TABLE:
                layout = R.layout.cardview_tableview_withexpandability;
                View tblView = LayoutInflater
                        .from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new TblViewHolder(tblView);
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                layout = R.layout.lineseparatorforrecyclerview;
                View separatorView = LayoutInflater
                        .from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new SeparatorViewHolder(separatorView);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected viewType: " + viewType);
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    public class TblViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final Typeface iconFont = FontManager.getTypeface(context, FontManager.FONTAWESOME);

        private Button btnToday, btnYesterday, btnThisWeek, btnThisMonth;
        private TextView arrowexpandcollapseTextView, sectionNameTextView;

        TblViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            btnMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).create();

                    alertDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL,"OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });


                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_stats, null);
                    alertDialog.setView(content);

                    //Pulling String out of bundle
                    String goalreached = mBundle.getString("goalreached");   
                    String day = mBundle.getString("day");
                    String distance = mBundle.getString("distance");                        
                    String calories = mBundle.getString("calories");


                    ImageView imgdialogMain = content.findViewById(R.id.imgView_genderA);
                    ivGenderA.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_male);

                    TextView tvGoalReached = content.findViewById(R.id.txtView_dialog_goalreached);
                    tvGoalReached.setText(goalreached);


                    TextView tvDay = content.findViewById(R.id.txtView_day);
                    tvDay.setText(day);

                    TextView tvImgviewWalking = content.findViewById(R.id.imgView_walking);


                    TextView tvDistance = content.findViewById(R.id.txtView_distance);
                    tvDistance.setText(distance);

                    TextView tvImgviewFire = content.findViewById(R.id.imgView_fire);

                    TextView tvCaloriesBurned = content.findViewById(R.id.txtView_location);
                    tvCaloriesBurned.setText(calories);

                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Currently you are just making a new bundle in your fragment and adding strings to it then doing nothing with it, then in the adapter you are creating another new Bundle and trying to pull out strings that are not there.

To update the data you could try something like this in the adapter to be called when you need to update the data (I am not sure if the notifyDataSetChanged() will work from inside the adapter though):

```
//Update Bundle
public void updateView(Bundle bundle){
    mBundle = bundle;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: In the `Fragment`, something needs to be added to `RVItemsAdapter itemsListAdapter = new RVItemsAdapter(getContext());` as I now get this error: `(Context, Bundle) in RVItemsAdapter cannot be applied to (Context)`

Comment: @MacaronLover you need to add the constructor I posted to your Adapter class, and create the bundle object in the adapter class.   EDIT: I am re-posting your adapter class with the changes.

Comment: That would mean I'd have to create a new adapter every time I want to use different Strings (which isn't efficient at all). Is there seriously no way of using a Fragment for this scenario?

Comment: You could make a method to pass in a new bundle, with the new strings. Then make a call to update the adapter.

Comment: Please update your answer so that it can help others and so that I can accept someone's answer

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the extras from a new Bundle here:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String goalreached = bundle.getString("goalreached");
...
```

You need to get the bundle where you stored that info. A bundle is only a "container" of info, so you need to store it and then retrieve it.

You are never saving the bundle anywhere, so you can't read it later.

I'm not sure what you want to do here, so I can't give you an example, but just check out this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("goalreached",  getResources().getString(R.string.goal_reached));
bundle.putString("day",  getResources().getString(R.string.today));
bundle.putString("distance",  getResources().getString(R.string._3_2_km));
bundle.putString("calories",  getResources().getString(R.string._213_kcal));
```

You are creating that bundle, then storing info, and that's it. You are never storing it anywhere.

The basic usage of a bundle is storing it on an Intent, then retrieving that intent and getting the bundle.